# How to center text horizontally and vertically in cojunction with 'writing-mode: sideways-lr'?

Tags: css

I have a TD/DIV with some text inside. I made so that the text is displayed in the center of TD/DIV . But I want the text to be in center using `writing-mode: sideways-lr`. How can I do this?

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: solid;
  display: table-cell;
}

.side {
  writing-mode: sideways-lr;
}
```

```html
<div>My text</div>
<br>
<div class="side">My text</div>
```

[Code here](https://jsfiddle.net/37jn9xmk/)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider an extra span where you apply the property and better use `writing-mode: vertical-rl;transform: scale(-1);` to have better support (your code works only on Firefox actually)

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: solid;
  display: table-cell;
}

.side span {
  /* writing-mode: sideways-lr; */
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: scale(-1);
}
```

```html
<div>My text</div>
<br>
<div class="side"><span>My text</span></div>
```

Comment: I can't believe there is no universally accepted method between browsers (only using tricks like this). Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I update the question. In Firefox do not work. I put also an image.

Comment: @Junior it's working fine on my firefox, what version are you using?

Comment: Version 74.0 (64.b). Try to resize window. The text will appear just like in photo, outside the cell.

Comment: I believe it is a bug. If you change directly in DOM some attributes, Firefox starts to show things OK. But just adding `.grf_arie td {text-align:center}` do nothing. Firefox fails to show things right at first time. Update: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wosp5za0/)

Comment: I was using this in an actual table, and I had to **remove** `display: table-cell;` to get it to work :shrug: